# How to scale a write intesive application with a SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, scalability

I am studying about many databases lately and the one thing I can't get the hang of is how to scale a write intensive application in SQL Server, I'm talking about native features, not third party software. I read about Federated Databases that seems to be something close to this, but I'm not sure if it is the best way since it seems to me that is way more read focused than write focused. I make myself clear that it is just an hypothetical situation and I do not have precise information of budget and pain points, I'm just assuming that I have a write intensive application (let's say 30/70) and I diagnosed that the bottleneck is on the database because it doesn't have enough CPU power and I want to scale with more servers therefore making a cluster, something like Oracle RAC.

Comment: Please provide a lot more background information such as the current pain points, budget restraints, current methods being looked at and so fourth.  Unfortunately with the data provided this question will be closed very soon.  Federation is just 1 of many solutions out there and you might be just grasping at straws at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using SQL Server 2014, you could have a look at In-memory OLTP tables (nee Hekaton).  They are suitable to write-intensive applications and there is a published pattern called [Shock Absorber](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2013/09/19/in-memory-oltp-common-design-pattern-high-data-input-rate-shock-absorber.aspx).  Start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186.aspx).